# Default catalog for stored macro SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

By default it is defined to store macros at WORK.SASMACR.
However at my site location for macros storage is different and I do not know where it is.
Can I find the default macros catalog and view what is inside?

Comment: Are you talking about a SAS Autocall macro library?

Comment: @Joe Here is what I am talking about - It is arranged for my SAS environment to automatically launch certain autoexec file, which contains %include statements to compile some macros each time new session of SAS is activated. Howewer if I perform following request:
proc catalog cat=work.sasmacr;
contents;
It gives:
ERROR: Catalog WORK.SASMACR does not exist.
So I believe that all macros being compiled at my SAS session are stored somewhere else. My question is how to find out where all compiled macros are stored in my SAS environment.

Comment: Is it compiling them, or is it pointing to a Sas Autocall macro facility and/or stored compiled macros?

Comment: Particularly, do you see a `/store` at the end of the %macro definition statement?

Comment: @Joe throughout the autoexec file there is nothing like autocall library or /store option. That is the point, that it is not clear where macros are stored then..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below effects of system options SASMSTORE + MSTORED and STORE option in macro definition on location of the compiled macros - could be something similar was used on your site.

```
option sasmstore=sasuser mstored;

%macro _mstore /store;
%put This is macro with mstore;
%mend;


%macro _nomstore;
%put This is macro without mstore;
%mend;

proc options option=sasmstore;
run;
```

Use DICTIONARY.CATALOGS to list macros compiled in your session.

```
proc sql;
create table macros as
select * from dictionary.catalogs where objtype='MACRO';
quit;
```

Comment: In new session
proc options option=sasmstore;
run;
gives me
SASMSTORE=        Specifies the libref of a SAS catalog for stored compiled SAS macros.
Thus by default there is no lib ref for macro storage. But if I invoke a macro, that is present in autoexec file, this macro will work notwithstanding I have not compiled it at this session. Ok, fine, but then it must be stored at WORK.SASMACR. However if I write proc catalog cat=work.sasmacr; contents; It says that there is no such catalog at all... There are no macros I am looking for (that are compiled by default) in dictionary.catalogs either.

Comment: So those are autocall macros compiled just at first execution. You'll find them in dictionary after that.

Answer (score 0):

You have **three option** to find **macros** `

**1.**

```
    proc catalog catalog=work.SASMACR;
    contents;
    run;
```

**2.**

```
   proc catalog catalog=work.SASMAC1;
    contents;
    run;
```

**3.**

```
        proc sql;
        create table macros as
        select * from dictionary.catalogs where objtype='MACRO';
        quit;
```

Comment: SASMACR is used when you launch SAS the old fashioned way. SASMAC1 is used when you use an application server to launch SAS instead, for example when using Enterprise Guide or SAS/Studio as your front end.